Action of matrices on right vector spaces
Let $V$ be a right (finite-dimensional) vector space over the (not necessarily commutative) division ring $\ell$. If we represent linear maps as matrices, then how do these matrices act on the elements of $V$ (presented by column vectors) ?

We apply matrices to column vectors to the left to represent linear maps between right vector spaces. Or apply matrices to row vectors from the right to represent linear maps between left vector spaces.


Definition: Let $R$ be a ring. A $\textbf{right $R$-module}$ is an additive abelian group $A$ together with a function $A\times R\to A$ such that for all $r,s\in R$ and $a,b\in A:$(i)(a+b)r=ar+br (ii)a(r+s)=ar+as (iii)(as)r=a(sr).
If $R$ is a division ring, then a $\textbf{unitary}$(i.e. $a1_R=a$ for all $a\in A)$ $R$-module is called a right vector space.

Suppose that $\dim V=n$. In this case, $\ell=\{T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}| \det(T)\neq 0\}$ since all nonzero elements should have their own inverse.
Given any $\begin{pmatrix}v_1& v_2& \ldots & v_n \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}u_1& u_2 &\ldots &u_n \end{pmatrix}\in V$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}& \ldots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} &\ldots & a_{2n}\\ 
\vdots &  \vdots& \ddots& \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\ldots& a_{nn}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12}& \ldots & b_{1n} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} &\ldots & b_{2n}\\ 
\vdots &  \vdots& \ddots& \vdots \\ b_{n1} & b_{n2} &\ldots& b_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\in \ell$,
easy to verify the above four conditions, where $A=V$ and $R=\ell.$
So it can only be presented by row vectors.
